# How to read a string from a file with getline in c++?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, fstream

I have 2 voids(save and load). save writes in the file and load loads from file. The problem is that when I try to read from that file it only reads one word, even with getline.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

float r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, puncte, rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4, rc5, rc6, rc7, rc8, rc9, rc10, var;
string q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10;

void save()
{
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Public\\IntrebariTest.txt");
outfile << q1 << " " << q2 << " " << q3 << " " << q4 << q5 << " " << q6 << " " << q7 << " " << q8 << " " << q9 << " " << q10 << rc1 << " " << rc2 << " " << rc3 << " " << rc4 << rc5 << " " << rc6 << " " << rc7 << " " << rc8 << " " << rc9 << " " << rc10;
outfile.close();
}
void load()
{
ifstream infile;
infile.open("C:\\Users\\Public\\IntrebariTest.txt");
infile.getline(cin, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10);
infile >> rc1 >> rc2 >> rc3 >> rc4 >> rc5 >> rc6 >> rc7 >> rc8 >> rc9 >> rc10;
infile.close();
}
```

So if anyone knows what causes the problem, please comment! Thanks!
And the error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::getline(std::istream&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::string&)'|
```

Comment: frankly, the problem is that you are guessing how `getline` works. There is no overload that takes 11 arguments. Your code will cause a compiler error that you should include in the question

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: I added the error inthe post

Comment: I think you're using getline wrong. This link might help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: You are doing it totally wrong because you should implement it according to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Not

```
infile.getline(cin, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10);
```

but

```
getline(infile, q1);
getline(infile, q2);
getline(infile, q3);
getline(infile, q4);
getline(infile, q5);
getline(infile, q6);
getline(infile, q7);
getline(infile, q8);
getline(infile, q9);
getline(infile, q10);
```

Also if you are going to read lines then you need to output lines.

Not

```
outfile << q1 << " " << q2 << " " << q3 << " " << q4 << q5 << " " << q6 << " " << q7 << " " << q8 << " " << q9 << " " << q10 << rc1 << " " << rc2 << " " << rc3 << " " << rc4 << rc5 << " " << rc6 << " " << rc7 << " " << rc8 << " " << rc9 << " " << rc10;
```

but

```
outfile << q1 << "\n" << q2 << "\n" << q3 << "\n" << 
    q4 << "\n" << q5 << "\n" << q6 << "\n" << q7 << "\n" << 
    q8 << "\n" << q9 << "\n" << q10 << "\n" << 
    rc1 << " " << rc2 << " " << rc3 << " " << rc4 << " " << rc5 << " " << rc6 << " " << rc7 << " " << rc8 << " " << rc9 << " " << rc10;
```

Of course this much repetition in your code should be alerting you to the fact that there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also can you explain the other way to do this?

Comment: @D0WN70AD use an array of strings q[] and than use a loop to fill the strings q[i]

Comment: Use a vector (or an array) and a loop.